# Which PDE textbook?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am curious if anyone has any experience with the following books.

- [Partial Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-0059-5) by Fritz John
- [An Introduction to Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Nonlinear+Partial+Differential+Equations,+2nd+Edition-p-9780470225950) (2nd edition) by J. David Logan

Is one book more theoretical than the other? Which do you believe is better suited for a first time learner of PDEs?

Comment: Fritz John is a classic but that doesn’t necessarily mean I recommend it. The book by Logan that you linked to is about nonlinear partial differential equations. Did you mean to link to Logan’s other book, Applied Partial Differential Equations? I recommend Strauss.

Comment: No. There is a class being offered at my university which uses Logan’s book which I linked. A class using Fritz’s book is being taught the semester after (spring of 2024), so I am trying to figure out which would be better to take first.

Comment: Fritz John's book *may* not be suitable for a first timer. However, a lot depends on the person who is teaching the course.

Comment: A course on Nonlinear partial differential equations might not cover the standard, fundamental material on linear partial differential equations that is typically covered first. Personally I’d be hesitant to start with a course on *nonlinear* PDEs.